# Counting the same actions with Firebase (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a `TableView`. When I tap by cell starts playing an audioplayer with user audio, I want to count how many times it was played. Now I have

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let record = self.records[indexPath.row]
        let uid = record.userUid
        self.dictionaryValues = ["playingCount": Int(record.playingCount)+1]
        Database.database().reference().child("records").child(uid).child(record.recordId).updateChildValues(self.dictionaryValues, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to save user info into db:", err)
                return
            }
            print("Successfully add 1 playing to total count")
        })

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

This method works only once when I lauch the app and add 1 to `Int` property of record in Firebase, but second tap on the same cell doesn't plus 1 to `playingCount`. How correctly count `playingCount` everytime I tap the same cell

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the record inside success completion block , so next time you click it reads the last value

```
print("Successfully add 1 playing to total count")
record.playingCount += 1
```

Comment: Got this error  `Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: function call returns immutable value`

Comment: make `playingCount` var not let